# Check which view presented the current view

Tags: ios

I am trying to check which view presented the current view as there are many views that could have brought me there.

Is there code that i can use to determine if it was a specific view? If it was the sepecific view that i want, i need to do something on viewDidLoad.

Comment: Do you want the view that presented a specific subview, or do you want the view controller that brought you where you are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you should do. A view shouldn't care which view presented it. That is fragile and it doesn't scale well.

A proper approach would be for your view to have one or more properties that can be set by whatever will present the new view. Then the view can display itself accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say "view" you really mean `UIViewController`.  You will find that `UIViewController` has a [`presentingViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller) property you can access to find the view controller that presented it.  (If this is not the scenario you're working with, you need to provide more specific information.)

A better pattern may be to instead pass a boolean or enum to your view controller's `init` method that controls the behavior.